# How can i detect number of segments in a circle in a skeletonized image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology, scikit-image

I have a skeleton image of wheels with 2,4, or 6 diameters drawn.
I have also branched point coordinates.

I think about 2 ways for detecting the different wheels:

1. Counting black areas inside the circle
2. counting diameters drawn

In both cases i do not know how could i implement them.

[image: wheel 1]
[image: wheel 2]
[image: wheel 3]
[image: wheel 4]
[image: wheel 5]

As you can see, wheels are not perfect skeletonized, and so it is harder detecting differences.

This is the code i use for skeletonization:

first of all i binarize image, i dilate and then skeletonize.

```
from skimage import io
import scipy
from skimage import morphology
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import mahotas as mah
import pymorph as pm
import pymorph

complete_path = "wheel1.jpg"
gray = cv2.imread(complete_path,0)
print(gray.shape)
cv2.imshow('graybin',gray)
cv2.waitKey()

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
imgbnbin = thresh
print("shape imgbnbin")
print(imgbnbin.shape)
cv2.imshow('binaria',imgbnbin)
cv2.waitKey()

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) 
graydilate = cv2.dilate(imgbnbin, element) #imgbnbin
graydilate = cv2.dilate(graydilate, element)
#graydilate = cv2.erode(graydilate, element)

cv2.imshow('dilate',graydilate)
cv2.waitKey()   

#SKELETONIZE
out = morphology.skeletonize(graydilate>0)
skel = out.astype(float)
cv2.imshow('scikitimage',skel)
cv2.waitKey()
io.imsave('wheel.jpg', skel)    
sk = skel
print(sk.shape)
```

Original images:

[image: wheel 1]
[image: wheel 2]
[image: wheel 3]
[image: wheel 4]
[image: wheel 5]

Comment: I solved ,with a better skeletonization (scikit-image is good but also mahotas libraries) and retrieving contoursof every image i can count the black region and recognize a wheel with 2,4 or 6 diameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also apply dilation to connect lines almost touching and use the [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to identify the compartments